# Error invoking autoreconf from Eclipse using Autotools plugin

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, autoconf

I installed the Autotools plugin for Eclipse from: http://www.eclipse.org/linuxtools/projectPages/autotools/.

I then imported an existing C++-project by first creating a new C++-project in Eclipse CDT, then importing the source files, and then converting the project to a Autotools project. However, after this conversion I get an error message that says

```
Invoking autoreconf in build directory: /home/user/Development/cpp/workspace/testproject

sh autoreconf -i 
sh: Can't open autoreconf

Configuration failed with error
```

The only files I have in my project that is related to autoconf is `configure.ac`, `Makefile.am`, `src/Makefile.am`. It is working fine to build the project using `autoreconf --install` from the command line.

Why does it try to launch `autoreconf -i` using `sh`? If I try that from the command line, it doesn't work either (the file `autoreconf` is not found). When I invoke it from the command line, I invoke it without `sh`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

In my Ubuntu 11.04, `dash` was the default target for `/bin/sh` and it appears that eclipse is getting tripped up by this.

You can change the link with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash`. Choose "No" to restore `/bin/sh` as a link to `bash`.

Comment: Ah, that might be it! I'll check it as soon as possible and report back here. Thanks.